# limit user storage size for each user django

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-admin

I'm trying to limit user storage i already set up foreign key and all but was wondering how can i achieve this.if anyone can point me to the right direction I'm stuck.

here is my model.py

```
class Document(models.Model):
    docfile = models.FileField(upload_to=only_filename)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='uploaded_files')
```

Answer (score 2):

change setting variable FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE to limit max size
check this [uploadfile](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/#changing-upload-handler-behavior)

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to give the user a total size limit for his/her storage? Does each user have the same amount or can it be different?

I would think if it can be different you'd first of all need a [custom user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model) or some other model that keeps track of the user's storage limit. Alternately, if you just make all users have the same limit you can skip creating a model.

After that, you'll need some program to calculate how much storage the user has used. One way to achieve that would be to make your `upload_to` field upload to a user-specific directory, something like:

```
class Document(models.Model):
    docfile = models.FileField(upload_to=USERNAME + '/' + only_filename)
```

And then, somewhere *before* the file gets uploaded, you can do something like this (in the views.py? in a custom model validator with a parameter?):

```
import os
def get_user_storage(username):
    user_files = os.listdir(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(UPLOAD_PATH), username)
    total = sum(os.path.getsize(fl) for fl in user_files)
    return total < WHATEVER_THE_MAXIMUM_IS
```

Once you have this function, you pass it a username, and it returns `True` if the user has not exceeded their storage or `False` if they have. One big problem with this, is that it will return `True` until a user exceeds his/her storage, but it doesn't care by how much. So if you set a storage limit of 1gb and a user with no previously uploaded files uploads something that's a terrabyte, this function on its own would allow it.

To prevent that from happening, you can set a maximum file upload limit.

I haven't tried any of this code, but I think it might get you started in piecing together a solution.